# Android Studio Databse Inspector not showing anything

Tags: android-studio, android-room, database-inspector

I am using Room on my APP, and recently I am trying to give Database Inspector a try. I am running it on API 27, but nothing is showing.

The package name was selected, and I don't see anything the manual was stating. I've watched couple videos, and there was no extra steps besides just running the app on API 26 or higher.

Is there anything else that I have to add to get it working ?
I could see that database inside Device explorer, and the app runs fine. I am using an Android Emulator and Android 4.1

Comment: same here, running API 29, did you figure it out? I'm running LineageOS, might that be a reason?

Comment: When I run the emulator at API 29, the inspector works fine. On my LineageOS phone with same API it is not working..